# Java Spring JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm a Spring noob and I'm struggling with it.

Basically before starting develop my Server with Spring in conjunction with JPA I tried to start a simple example just to get used to this framework.
I've already get succeded in make Spring working with some frameworks as Log4J, Swagger and others. Now I'm trying to work with JPA and there are some points i can find out the solution.

I saw some blogs on how to develop with it and from all thousands options i choose to create my Repository Interfece and `extend Repository<T, ID>`. You can see my code bellow:

```
package com.example.model;
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    public String name;

    public Person(){}
}

package com.example.repository;
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Integer> {
    Collection<Person> findAll();
}


package com.example.controller;
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<Person> getAll() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
}

package com.example;
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

And I also have the application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

When I put the server running I get the following exception:

```
: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.example.repository.PersonRepository com.example.controllers.PersonController.repo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.repository.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
: Stopping service Tomcat
: Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.example.repository.PersonRepository com.example.controllers.PersonController.repo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.repository.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I created a Github Repository to share the code [here](https://github.com/BrunoMNDantas/SpringJPA).

Any clue about what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the packages of your classes? Your repository is only automatically detected, if it's in the same or in a subpackage as the App class.

Comment: @dunni I've removed just to simplify but here they are:

package com.example.controllers;

package com.example.entities;

package com.example.repository;

package com.example;

Comment: Assume that you have all dependencies. In your App class, can you put this below the @SpringBootApplication:  @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example"). Then try again.

Comment: @KennyTaiHuynh

SpringBootApplication
ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example")
public class App {

Same exeption :S

Comment: I mean below the line @SpringBootApplication. In another line, put the @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example").

Comment: This is related to the packages structure check my answer.

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah renamed the packages but still with same exception

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml/gradle file? Looks a bit as if there's no Spring Data JPA on your class path.

Comment: @mp911de I share the code here https://github.com/BrunoMNDantas/SpringJPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing here is why you need to implements the base interface [Repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html) as doing so, you will not have usual CRUD operations. For such operations is better to implements [CrudRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html). Since you implement [CrudRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) no need to define a findAll() Method and many well known others you can find in doc mentioned.

Furthermore, when using `@SpringBootApplication` Spring boot use default values. If you see the @SpringBootApplication [definition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) you will see that :

> Many Spring Boot developers always have their main class annotated with @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan. Since these annotations are so frequently used together (especially if you follow the best practices above), Spring Boot provides a convenient @SpringBootApplication alternative.
>
> The @SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using  @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan with their default attributes: [...]

That means when using default values for ComponentScan your packages sturctures shloud be as following :

1. com.example.model -> your entities
2. com.example.repositoriy -> your repositories
3. com.example.controller -> controllers
4. com.example -> MainApplication class

Here is an example for [default project structure](http://www.javaenthusiasm.com/using-thymeleaf-in-spring-projects-part-2/)
The main Application Class should be in higher level package then the others. Unless you have to specify packages location with @ComponentScan.

As you are beginner with the framework. I suggest you to always see classes definitions in official documentation.

**UPDATE** :

Here is an example from one of my spring boot projects

[image]

Also see this [spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) for JPA

Comment: I tried to extend from CrudRepository, and renamed the packages to match the ones you refer, but still not working and getting the same exeption

Comment: The packages names are not important. The structure is. The application main class should be in package next higher than the others. See my edit

Comment: You are still stuck with it ?

Comment: @HassamAbdelilah Unfortunatly XD

Comment: The packages are good structured.You should remove the componentScan and EnableJpaRepositories from your main. 

Also in the pom.xml why having two dependencies for jpa ! spring-boot-starter-data-jpa is sufficent.

Comment: @HassamAbdelilah thanks for the help. The problem it was the 2nd dependency of JPA

Answer (score 1):

Just annotate your interface with @Repository. And if that doesnt work try adding @EnableJPARepositories to the main class.

Comment: With Repositories and EnableJpaRepositories i got a different exception.
Exception Could not autowire field: private com.example.repository.PersonRepository com.example.controllers.PersonController.repo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor

Comment: Just follow this https://github.com/joshlong/bootiful-microservices/blob/master/bootiful-applications/reservation-service/src/main/java/com/example/ReservationServiceApplication.java

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the @Repository annotation to your PersonRepository, that could be the reason it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your PersonRepository interface with @Respository, otherwise the spring context won't recognize it or create an implementation for it.