# ClassNotFoundException CrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm reading the [JPA docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/) on spring, and i'm trying to restructure my code.

What i have now:

*BrewerRepository*

```
@Repository
public class BrewerRepository {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "vivesPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Brewer> getAll() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*BrewerService*

```
@Service
public class BrewerService {

    @Autowired
    private BrewerRepository brewerRepository;

    public List<Brewer> getAll() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*HomeController*

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private BrewerService brewerService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {

        List<Brewer> brewers = this.brewerService.getAll();

        model.addAttribute("brewers", brewers);

        return "index";
    }
}
```

*PersistenceJPAConfig*

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class PersistenceJPAConfig{

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan("org.vives.model");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/beers;create=true");
        dataSource.setUsername( "app" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "app" );
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManager){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", "org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

With this code, the application starts without problems.

When i change the Repository and Service like this:

```
@Repository
public interface BrewerRepository extends CrudRepository<Brewer, Long> {

}

@Service
public class BrewerService {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "vivesPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private BrewerRepository brewerRepository;

    public List<Brewer> getAll() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'brewerService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brewerService' defined in file [.\glassfish-5.0\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\spring-mvc-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\org\vives\service\BrewerService.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.vives.service.BrewerService] from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)]]]
...
  Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'brewerService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brewerService' defined in file [.\glassfish-5.0\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\spring-mvc-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\org\vives\service\BrewerService.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.vives.service.BrewerService] from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brewerService' defined in file [.\glassfish-5.0\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\spring-mvc-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\org\vives\service\BrewerService.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.vives.service.BrewerService] from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.vives.service.BrewerService] from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)]
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1059)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1588)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1471)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:754)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1621)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1471)
    ... 92 more
]]
```

I've tried to look for an answer, but without success. Can someone explain to me why this is happening and tell me how I can fix it?

What I've tried so far:

- checked the dependencies
- deleted the .m2 folder and installed all
- dependencies again messed a bit with annotations
- changed a bit the project structure, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944587/java-spring-jpa-repository) post

EDIT:

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.vives</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-quickstart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>spring-mvc-quickstart</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <!-- Override Spring version -->
        <spring.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.1</jackson.version>
        <thymeleaf-extras-java8time-version>3.0.1.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-java8time-version>
        <!-- AssertJ is not a part of Spring IO platform, so the version must be provided explicitly -->
        <assertj-core-version>3.8.0</assertj-core-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <!-- Avoid issue #72 Could not initialize class org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver due to 'validation is not supported' -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>pull-parser</artifactId>
                    <groupId>pull-parser</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: If you are using Maven post your POM (maby u need spring-data)

Comment: @mtt2p done, but i don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amr Alaa mentioned, there was an issue with the dependencies. I solved my problem by creating a new project in a different folder and adding the dependencies again.

Answer (score 5):

Came to this error [ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository ] was using springboot dev tools auto build

but stopped the program -> clean -> run solved the issue on my end.

Answer (score 1):

the CrudRepository class is not found which means that the pom dependencies are not defined well. The Crud repository is defined the spring-data-jpa and it is included but i think the problem could be found in the spring different dependencies that you are using that may conflict with each other. for example some dependencies may be included as a child dependencies in others, so they must not be included again. Also you must make sure that the spring dependencies versions are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I cleared the .m2 repository (path e.g. `C:\Users\Hetal Rachh\.m2\repository`) and then did a `mvn clean install` build and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The Constructor Injection is missing like:

```
@Autowired 
public BrewerService(BrewerRepository brewerRepository) {
     this.brewerRepository = brewerRepository
}
@Override
public List<Brewer> getAll() {
    return brewerRepository.findAll();
}
```

Comment: I've tried that already, basically it's a different syntax, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I usually update the project and let it rebuild, then restart the program in the spring boot dashboard.